# WordPress Fallback Thumbnail image by size

Tags: wordpress

I have more than one custom thumbnail size.

For example:

```
<?php
add_image_size( 'sizeOne', 300, 100 );
add_image_size( 'sizeTwo', 600, 200 );
?>
```

I show the thumbnail with the function:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'sizeOne' ); ?>
```

And, if the image does not exist (if I haven't set the custom thumbnail in Admin area), the fallback image will be `default-thumbnail.png`. This process is made by this code in `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    // If there is no post thumbnail,
    // Return a default image
    if ( '' == $html ) {
        return '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-thumbnail.png" width="300" height="100" />';
    }
    // Else, return the post thumbnail
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_post_thumbnail_html' );
?>
```

**The problem is** that the fallback image is the same for all thumbnail sizes. As it's 300x100, it is perfect to `sizeOne`, but is too small for `sizeTwo`.

How can I  "check" if the thumbnail asked is `sizeOne` or `sizeTwo` and then return the correct fallback image?

–

Ps: I know the other way to do this, *but that's not what I want*.

```
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail( 'sizeOne' );
    } else {
?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/default-thumbnail.jpg" width="300" height="100" />
<?php 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the additional parameters of the [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/).

```
<?php
function filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size ) {
    // If there is no post thumbnail,
    // Return a default image
    if ( '' == $html ) {
        if ( 'sizeTwo' == $size ) {
            return '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-thumbnail2.png" width="600" height="200" />'; 
        } else {
            return '<img src="' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/default-thumbnail.png" width="300" height="100" />';
        }

    }
    // Else, return the post thumbnail
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'filter_post_thumbnail_html', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: That is correct, Jrod. Can you just explain the `10, 4` at the end? Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Hugo Definitely. 10 is the priority that the filter should run. 10 is the default for filters/actions. 4 is the number of parameters that your function will be accepting. This particular filter passes 5 parameters but you don't have to use all the them and in this case we are only using 4 of them.